# Building AndroidManifest.xml File

Tags: android, android-manifest

The AndroidManifest.xml file is placed in the root directory, and contains nodes to activity and other app components required to launch an android app. So in what stage of building/deploying an android app is this file built? How should it be viewed in the context of launching an android application?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use Android Studio. When you create your project the manifest is built/created automatically. Without manifest you cannot launch your app at all, so it has to be present at the time you want to actually launch it. Ideally, you shouldn't have to worry about actively writing or creating your Manifest file.

To give an example, as you mentioned - Manifest file must contain your activities. However, there is no need to write them down yourself. With Android Studio, clicking on your package and selecting New -> Activity will automatically create your Activity java file, xml for menu and layout and **important for you - automatically** create reference to your activity in your manifest file. It is convenient and prevents typo mistakes as well.